# rox-filer hangs on listxattr when NFS is concerned

Tags: linux, debian, nfs

Since very recently, `rox-filer` hangs for me as soon as it is supposed to display a directory where a NFS is mounted. `strace rox-filer -n` shows the following:

```
[snip]
open("/home/vinter/.icons/Adwaita/index.theme", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/cursors/sb_h_double_arrow", O_RDONLY) = 11
fstat(11, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=15776, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f42d96bb000
read(11, "Xcur\20\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\3\0\0\0\2\0\375\377\30\0\0\0004\0\0\0\2\0\375\377"..., 4096) = 4096
lseek(11, 0, SEEK_SET)                  = 0
read(11, "Xcur\20\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\3\0\0\0\2\0\375\377\30\0\0\0004\0\0\0\2\0\375\377"..., 4096) = 4096
close(11)                               = 0
munmap(0x7f42d96bb000, 4096)            = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"\22\0\n\0C\0@\3\301\1\0\0\301\1\0\0\10\0\0\0\20\0\0\0l\0\5\0\0\0\0\0"..., 2644}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 2644
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\34\0!\1C\0@\3\301\1\0\0\201\352q\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 64
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\0001\1\0\0\0\0N\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
recvmsg(3, 0x7fffd0fc3050, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
write(5, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
lstat("/mnt/nas/pub", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
listxattr("/mnt/nas/pub", 
[hangs]
```

`nautilus`, on the other hand, has no problems, but I like some of `rox-filer`'s unique features too much to change. What is happening here? Mind you, the NFS is working perfectly, it is only this `listxattr` which fails. The same behavior occurs when I `cd` inside the NFS and start it from there - it receives the file listing, but hangs on `listxattr`.

My mount options are `_netdev,rw,soft,bg,noauto,noatime,intr,x-systemd.automount`, but they have no bearing on this - `defaults` shows the same behavior. System is Debian Sid (dist-upgrade Thursday or so), Kernel is 3.15-10.dmz.1-liquorix-amd64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rox Filer supports reading Extended Attributes, but these extended attributes are not supported by NFS (and according to the developers, will never be).  This would cause the listxattr (List Extended Attributes) system call to fail.

Perhaps there is a bug in the software, and the code is incorrectly dealing with the returned error code and hanging.  Reporting the bug would be your only option, unless there is some way within Rox Filer to turn off reading/displaying extended attributes.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! It's strange that it stopped working so suddenly, but maybe there was some kind of regression that I didn't notice when updating. Unfortunately, the project is rather dead, so I ended up biting the bullet and switching to `spacefm`. While a bit more cluttered, it's even more flexible than `rox-filer`, so it's an alright tradeoff.